# How to deactivate method when I don't need it?

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, textbox

I have WPF database application. My database has 10 tables, but one of them has a different number of columns. I can edit data with Textboxes. So I made a method for create more Textboxes. If I select table with ten columns there are ten Textboxes, but if I select different table with less columns, there are still ten Textboxes.

All my tables except one have only two columns, so I created two textboxes in XAML and a method to create the remaining columns when the ten-columns-table is selected.
This is the example my method:

```
public void AddTb()
    {
        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        tb2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb2.Width = 60;
        tb2.Height = 23;
        tb2.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        tb2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x36, 0x4d, 0x63));
        tb2.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 229);
        Grid.Children.Add(tb2);

    }
```

this is a condition for calling the method:

```
string select = this.MySimpleStringProperty;
        if (select == "konzole")
        {
            AddTb();
        }
```

My list:

```
public string MySimpleStringProperty { get; set; }
        public List<string> MyListProperty { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "konzole", "výrobce", "typ", "platforma", "barva", "edice", "site", "uložiště", "velikost_uložiště", "mechanika" };
```

Comment: How are you getting the data? Wouldn't it make more sense to iterate the columns you have and add a textblock with property name: and a textbox to edit that property. Driven by your metadata. Then when you add another table with different columns, it'll just work.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid

Comment: Have you considered adding your editing for each property to an itemscontrol like this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29777.wpf-property-list-editing.aspx

Comment: Yes, I think it was. But this is a homework, I have to follow the task.

Comment: You need to remove the `TextBoxes` when you don't want them any longer. `Grid.Children.Clear()` removes all children.

Comment: @mm8 Oh, yes, it's logic :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just maintain it in AddTb method if you have a list of elements you can maintain a list and check with `.Any()`

```
  public void AddTb()
  { 
         if(MySimpleStringProperty != "konzole")
             return;
            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            tb2.Width = 60;
            tb2.Height = 23;
            tb2.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            tb2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x36, 0x4d, 0x63));
            tb2.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 229);
            Grid.Children.Add(tb2);

   }
```

**Based on Comment**

```
List<string> ProperString = new List<string>();//Global
ProperString.Add("konzole");
ProperString.Add("Other Stuff");

 if (!ProperString.Any(x => x == MySimpleStringProperty))
                    return;
```

U can use `.Contains()` also

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ZlyVlk Chek now

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `TextBoxes` when you don't want them any longer.

Calling `Grid.Children.Clear()` removes all children.